# How do I test Amazon MWS API via Java?

Tags: java, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

Apparently there is no sandbox for Amazon MWS API and I confirmed with customer support.

> "At this time we do not offer staging or test accounts. Though we have
>   had sandbox or staging accounts in the past, it is no longer offered
>   and the only place for the item or order feeds to go is the actual
>   Production side of Amazon.
>
> Sincere Apologies for the inconvenience this issue has caused to you.
>
> As you can imagine, bad information added for a product could impact
>   your seller account or other seller accounts. Bad information on an
>   order could also impact your sellers account or your buyer account.
>   Due to these risks we no longer offer test accounts at this time."

This is the most absurd statement I heard for not offering sandbox for testing Java MWS API and we have to resort to using our production account and we had several accidental near purges of our production inventory.

Someone please tell me the right way to test MWS Java API in sandbox/test environment?

Amazon can't be this fucking stupid to ask devs to use production environment to "minimize risks"

I am pretty sure I am the dummy over here and can't figure out a way to test our API without jeopardizing our production data.

How to test java MWS API on Amazon?

Comment: Create another Amazon Seller account with fake listings?

Comment: @MrOffice, You need to pay $39 to be professional seller to access the API and you are not allowed to have two seller accounts else Amazon will shutdown both accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have to use this procedure for testing with the MWS API:

Open a real seller account that you will not really use to sell, and pay a monthly fee ( as the free seller account does not allow MWS use).

If your company has a seller account and is going to open a second account for testing, they need to get approval from Amazon before doing this, as it is normally against the rules for one company to have two seller accounts.

From the new seller account, submit a request for a Developer ID (aka access to MWS).  There are new strict requirements to get this access to MWS as of the writing of this post.  So before requesting access, you need to study their Acceptable Use Policy and their Data Protection Policy.  Also they are saying the review process takes 30 days.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/

Comment: Is this the only way to test my APIs? Can I not use any other platform just to ensure that my code works perfectly and now I can use it at production level?